# TCP/IP Linux C Programming

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I am having a client server application and I am facing synchronization issues because of which application behavior is getting affected. I have created Non blocking sockets on both client and server side and set the timeout to <10 ms.
I have also disabled nagles algorithm to improve performance using TCP_NODELAY but still there are some frames which are not being received in the given timeout limit. Application frame rate is 10 ms, i.e. every 10 ms data from server is sent to client, processed at client and and sent back to server from client. It is clear that client processing takes minimum time and the issue is happening because of delay observed between data sent on the server side and the time it receives on the client side.
I am posting a sample of 23 transactions on both the server side and client side along with frame id and time stamps. Please suggest a solution to avoid any frame miss and what can be done so that there is no latency observed between the data sent from the server and received at the client as shown in the image for frame 19 and 20.

```
Server_Send                     Client_recv                      Client_Send           Server_Recv
1: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.516997   1: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.517137    1:08-01-2017 12:09:06.520692    1: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.520776
2: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.526003   2: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.526977    2: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.527227   2: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.527277
3: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.536623   3: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.537347    3:08-01-2017 12:09:06.538064    3: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.538145
4: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.548041   4: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.548244    4:08-01-2017 12:09:06.553930    4: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.553984
5: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.558734   5: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.560445    5:08-01-2017 12:09:06.562220    5: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.562275
6: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.570256   6: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.571268    6:08-01-2017 12:09:06.573355    6: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.573410
7: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.581230   7: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.581581    7: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.583369   7: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.583415
8: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.591663   8: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.592463    8:08-01-2017 12:09:06.593920    8: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.593969
9: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.602883   9: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.603185    9:08-01-2017 12:09:06.605446    9: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.605493
10: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.613645  10: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.613682   10:08-01-2017 12:09:06.616006   10: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.616074
11: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.626245  11: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.626271   11:08-01-2017 12:09:06.626572   11: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.626656
12: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.636939  12: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.637014   12:08-01-2017 12:09:06.639457   12: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.639514
13: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.647869  13: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.647869   13:08-01-2017 12:09:06.648664   13: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.648709
14: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.659493  14: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.659696   14:08-01-2017 12:09:06.660737   14: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.660788
15: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.670809  15: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.671052   15:08-01-2017 12:09:06.674226   15: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.674273
16: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.681847  16: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.681891   16:08-01-2017 12:09:06.682959   16: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.683012
17: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.692172  17: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.692213   17:08-01-2017 12:09:06.693255   17: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.693351
18: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.704028  18: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.704249   18:08-01-2017 12:09:06.705936   18: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.706016
19: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.715104  19: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.721432   19:08-01-2017 12:09:06.721995   19: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.722050
20: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.725430  20: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.732182   20:08-01-2017 12:09:06.735507   NA
21: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.736586  21: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.742824   21:08-01-2017 12:09:06.745176   20: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.736587
22: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.747406  22: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.753496   22:08-01-2017 12:09:06.755014   21: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.747448
23: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.758205  23: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.764413   23:08-01-2017 12:09:06.764537   22: 08-01-2017 12:09:06.758251
```

[TCP Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9xKQ.jpg)

Comment: Show some code!

Comment: Insert those stats into the question as formatted text. Those stats shows that the server timer drifts, i.e. the delays between `Sever_Sent` timestamps are greater than 10ms.

Comment: You are right, that is 1 more issue that the Server timer is drifting but it is not as critical as the one mentioned above.

Comment: You can never guarantee that a network packet will be delivered within some predetermined time span. It also sounds like you're expecting TCP to not be a streaming protocol.

Comment: I guess by disabling nagles algorithm on both Server as well as Client's side, there are buffering and flushing issues which is causing a delay/lag in sending and receiving.

Comment: 10ms?  That seems very short for any network timer:(

Comment: Also, TCP cannot transfer messages longer than one byte.  Anything larger requires a protocol on top, eg: 'messages are terminated by a CR' or 'messages are prefixed by a header struct that indicates the message length'.  If you don't have such a protocol, you can only exchange byte streams, as commented by @molbdnilo.  If you do, you should have detailed it in the question.

Comment: Input and output data are merely 40-50 bytes and 10 ms seems to be a decent amount of time as shown in the data above.

Comment: Please compare Row 18 and Row 19 and observe the delay happening in Row 19 from Server to Client Receiving which indicates a difference of 6 ms(721432-715104). Can someone suggest why is this happening?

Comment: @PiyushJain It could be sunspots, for all we know. Or maybe a cat tripped over a wire somewhere in Wisconsin - network communication is unpredictable. TCP guarantees that everything you send on the stream will have arrived as a stream *at some point* in the future, but that's all you get.

Comment: 6ms is next-to nothing on a network.  Also, ' merely 40-50 bytes' is 40-50 times too large, if your protocol is plain TCP.  Sending 40-50 byes and expecting a guaranteed reply from a peer within 10ms is umm.. 'very fragile', even using a protocol with creedence.

Comment: You can have a reliable stream of data to consume at a fixed rate by  buffering data, or you can have lower average latency by not buffering data.  You cannot have both.

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin and molbdnilo

Comment: If you want a real solution to avoid any frame miss, you have to go with something like AVB ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Video_Bridging ).  Doing so will require that all the network hardware along the messaging path support the AVB timing and bandwidth-reservation standards.  (needless to say this is overkill for most applications, and you'd be better off simply using UDP and high-priority dedicated I/O threads with large socket-buffers, and designing your application to elegantly handle the occasional packet drop)